# How to store values to create multi-field objects of same class

Tags: java

Java 8 - I need to create a bunch of multi-field objects of the same class for a certain feature of my program. I'm working within a somewhat messy legacy application, so my options are limited.

- I can't use a database
- The values will need to be stored in a different maven module
- constant values
- should all be stored in one place & easy to modify/add to by other developers later on

What I'd considered so far:

1. An enumeration of the names is already in use. Adding fields to these does tick all the boxes, but I'm still not certain what enums should/should not be used for.
2. A text file of some sort
3. Actually writing it all out (create(value,value,value...) Then add to list etc.) - seems messy as hell as I'll have 60+ objects to create

Newbie programmer who's still struggling with some basics. Sorry if this question is mindblowingly stupid.

Edit: Similar example: I'd like to create 35 dog objects, fields could be name, height, color, age. The objects will be created when the application starts and will always be the same.

First question would be whether using enum here is a bad idea, since the legacy program is already using one for the name.

Comment: Please try to share the actual scenario or the problem you are trying to solve ,
You can also explore concept of serialization of Object into file and deserialize file objects back to Java memory , but please try to share actual scenario or code where ever possible

Comment: You could store it in a configuration file, if it is a configuration. The format is up to you, you can have simple string, xml structure, Json, etc. Still, the question is a bit broad, and maybe there is a more elegant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need objects with fields added at runtime then consider using Map where keys are enum constants and values are objects.